# Zero inflated correlation

Tags: correlation

What is the best way to correlate zero-inflated count variables with a small sample size (n=~50 and N=99)?

Comment: You may need to provide more information. What do you mean by correlate? What are n and N?

Comment: By correlate, I mean a measure of association - something like pearson's r. N and n were typos; I just meant I have two sample sizes. So, for one variable, I have 50 males and 50 females and I want to correlate their scores together. For another variable, I have 99 males and 99 females and I want to correlate their scores. My variables are measures of delinquency counts, which are relatively rare events. Thanks so much for your response!!

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I have the same issue, but with ceiling values inflation.

Comment: This question only makes sense if the males and females are couples.  If not (and it seems unlikely with delinquency counts), perhaps "correlate" is the wrong term and the user really wanted to know about how to model a count variable as response and a factor (sex) as an explanatory variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many nonparametric measures of relation. There is even a whole book on the subject [*Nonparametric Measures of Association*by Gibbons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0803946643), which is one of the "green books" series from Sage, although I have not read this book.  [Agresti, in *Categorical Data Analysis*, has excellent coverage of these.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471360937)

For count data with a lot of 0's, you could use one of the ordinal measures.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not too many non-zero values, why not simply present the cross-table? Or graphically, the two bar charts?

@Peter -- the description of the book Nonparametric Measures of Association on Amazon mentions that it is for ordinal data, and you too mention using ordinal methods for count data. But are they really sufficiently similar?

Comment: Certainly count data are ordinal. They are also interval. However, when a lot of the entries are 0, then the interval level measures don't seem to be ideal. You more or less acknowledge this, implicitly, by suggesting a cross table.